update_email_resetdate keeps failing after update to 5.75.1: Unknown api version
This update_email_resetdate issue is reminiscent of an older one dealing with mail processing, but that has been fixed since.
The job log does not provide further information:

Parameters raw (from db settings):  minDays=0, maxDays=7
Parameters parsed (and passed to API method):  a:0:{}
Full message:  Finished execution of Validate Email Address from
Mailings. with result: Failure,
Error message: Unknown api version

There is nothing new in the detailed log after the job runs, so I'm stuck again. Any pointers?
As an aside: running the job with cv seemingly succeeds (doesn't get rid of the complaint on the backend though):
cv -vvv api job.execute update_email_resetdate minDays=0 maxDays=7

Box Requirements Checker
========================

> Using PHP 8.1.29

/.../ 
                                                                                                             
 [OK] Your system is ready to run the application.                                                           
                                                                                                             
/.../

Entity: job
Action: execute
Params: {
    "version": 3,
    "": null,
    "minDays": "0",
    "maxDays": "7",
    "debug": 1
}
{
    "is_error": 0,
    "undefined_fields": [
        "",
        "minDays",
        "maxDays"
    ],
    "version": 3,
    "count": 1,
    "values": 1,
    "xdebug": []
}

Don't know if that's relevant at all. It does generate two API Request Authorization failed backtraces in the full log, which might be a different problem. Also they mention different jobs (some code sharing?). Unfortunately the question asking specifically for pointers on such auth failures has no replies.
2024-08-18 18:09:41+0200  [debug] $API Request Authorization failed = 
#0 civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php(151): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("API Request Authorization failed", TRUE)
#1 civicrm-core/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php(256): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\DAOGetFieldsAction))
#2 civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php(93): Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractAction->execute()
#3 civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php(43): CRM_Utils_Mail_EmailProcessor::_process(TRUE, Object(CRM_Core_DAO_MailSettings), 0)
#4 civicrm-core/api/v3/Job.php(378): CRM_Utils_Mail_EmailProcessor::processBounces(0)
#5 civicrm-core/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_job_fetch_bounces((Array:2))
#6 civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php(156): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:8))
#7 civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php(79): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:8))
#8 civicrm-core/api/api.php(28): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("Job", "fetch_bounces", (Array:1))
#9 civicrm-core/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(135): civicrm_api("Job", "fetch_bounces", (Array:1))
#10 civicrm-core/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(73): CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJob(Object(CRM_Core_ScheduledJob))
#11 civicrm-core/api/v3/Job.php(118): CRM_Core_JobManager->execute(FALSE)
#12 civicrm-core/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_job_execute((Array:5))
#13 civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php(156): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:8))
#14 civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php(79): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:8))
#15 civicrm-core/api/api.php(28): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("job", "execute", (Array:5))
#16 phar://cv3/src/Command/ApiCommand.php(54): civicrm_api("job", "execute", (Array:5))
#17 phar://cv3/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(155): Civi\Cv\Command\ApiCommand->execute(Object(Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
/.../
#24 cv3(15): require("phar://cv")
#25 {main}

2024-08-18 18:09:41+0200  [debug] $API Request Authorization failed = 
#0 civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php(151): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("API Request Authorization failed", TRUE)
#1 civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php(79): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:8))
#2 civicrm-core/api/api.php(136): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("Group", "get", (Array:4))
#3 civicrm-core/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php(1872): civicrm_api3("Group", "get", (Array:4))
#4 civicrm-core/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php(1833): CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing::mailingACLIDs()
#5 civicrm-core/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php(79): CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing::mailingACL("m")
#6 civicrm-core/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php(2346): CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob::runJobs(NULL, NULL)
#7 civicrm-core/api/v3/Job.php(334): CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing::processQueue()
#8 civicrm-core/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_job_process_mailing((Array:1))
#9 civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php(156): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:8))
#10 civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php(79): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:8))
#11 civicrm-core/api/api.php(28): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("Job", "process_mailing", (Array:1))
#12 civicrm-core/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(135): civicrm_api("Job", "process_mailing", (Array:1))
/.../
#27 cv3(15): require("phar://cv")
#28 {main}

